# Setting a Float in text of JLabel results in NaN. Is there another way to store float value to JLabel?

Tags: java, string, floating-point, nan

Setting  a Float value to the JLabel gives me the result of NAN. 
I have tried converting the float to string and still the result is NAN. Is there another way to store float value to the JLabel?

***I Have tried the String.valueOf() but this the result is NAN.

```
int size = priority.size();
float avgtaf= 0.00f, avgta = 0.00f;
int  []ta = new int[size]; 

    for(int  i = 0 ; i < size; i++)  avgta += ta[i] ;  

    avgtaf = avgta / size; 

    String avetat = Float.toString(avgtaf);

                atatAns = new JLabel(avetat);
                atatAns.setFont(FONTB);
                atatAns.setBounds(270,300,200,30);
```

Comment: can you also add more info like avgta =? and size= ? is there any possibility that size could be zero.

Comment: wait i'll edit the question

Comment: Surely the NaN arises in `Float.toString()`? And what is the value of `size`?

Comment: You need to provide an [mre], including complete code that reproduces the problem. Partial code that you think illustrates some part of the failing code is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int  []ta = new int[size]; 
for(int  i = 0 ; i < size; i++)  avgta += ta[i] ;
```

^^^ are those line correct?

here: `ta` is not initialized with any value. And you do not use the `priority` array.
check if this could be:

```
for(int  i = 0 ; i < size; i++)  avgta += priority[i] ;
```

Comment: no. The priority variable is an arraylist, i just use it to determine the size of the array 'ta' and 'ta' is not null.

Comment: what values each of the ta[i] contains?

Comment: 1
3
6

size is 3

Comment: @knhrvs So why isn't that evident in your code? Why does it look like it's an array of zeros?

Comment: this is just a snippet of my code, and im completely sure that its not an array of zeros.

Comment: @knhrvs You're suppose to post a reproducible problem.

Comment: where  did you assign the values of 1, 3, 6 in  ta[] ?

Comment: i have seen the problem. The problem here is that  when im summing up all the elements in the array. the initialized value of avgta stays and is not overwritten by the new integer. 

for example:
1 + 3 + 6 = 10 should be the answer 
but it gives me:
1 + 3 + 6 = 0 10

Comment: @knhrvs That can only happen if the array contains all zeros or is zero length. I suggest the real issue is that `size` is zero so you are computing 0/0.

Comment: no its not 0. Im 100% sure. Maybe the problem here is the IDE that i am using

Comment: @knhrvs If it isn't zero, what is it? You were first asked that two hours ago. IDEs don't cause spurious NaNs. You need to stop all this guessing and post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

i have figured out the answer last week, and they are right the size variable contains zero at the first run. So what i did is that i put a trigger after the computation of the average so it will be executed once the computation is done. And i the NAN disappeared.